# Calculating number of non-null elements around an element in 2D array and assigning that number to element in that location

Tags: java, arrays

This is a part of code where I wanted to assign the number of "X" present around an element in grid. For example if the element at grid[2][2] has 3 "X" around it than program will calculate number of X's and assign that value to counter1, where I will store the values for further use. I was calculating for values that are not in edges so i>0 & J>0. I am getting an error as index out of bound.

Please help I am a novice programmer, so please pardon me if I am making a silly error

Thank You

```
int counter1 = 0;   
for(int i = 0;i<grid.length;i++){
 for (int j = 0;j<grid.length;j++){      
  //checking if it is not in the edge of grid and it doesnot contain "X"   
  if (grid[i][j] != "X" && i >0 && j>0) {
    for(int x = i-1; x <= i+1;x++){
     for (int y = j-1;y <= j+1;y++){
      if (grid[x][y] == "X")
        counter1++;
     }
    }
    //Calculating the number of X's around the element in array and assigning 
    //that value to string in that place
    System.out.println("Counter1 = "+ counter1);
    grid[i][j] = String.valueOf(counter1);
    counter1 = 0;
  }              
 }
}
```

Comment: change "if (grid[i][j] != "X" && i >0 && j>0)" to "if ( i >0 && j>0 && grid[i][j] != "X")". Cause before checking the values of i and j you are trying to access the grid. Hence throwing index out of exception.

Comment: changing the order of check is not changing anything the exception still exists...

Comment: find out at what statement the exception is thrown. Put a try catch block and print the error